# I tried resizing a video, but got different strange resolution than I wanted with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded a video that had some black bars (left and right), so I used the following command in FFmpeg to crop it and then resize it. I tested it on a 10 second clip to see what the result would look like. (I use a version of FFmpeg for android that uses a GUI, so the parts of the command that specify the input files and the output files are handled separately from the command.)

```
-ss 00:04:44 -to 00:04:54 -vf "crop=1870:20:20:0","scale=640x480:flags=lanczos"
```

The original video is an h264 mp4, with a resolution of 1920 x 1080. The resulting clip was supposed to be an h265 mp4, with a (cropped and then resized) resolution of 640 x 480. Instead, its resulting resolution is all over the place, depending on what I examine it with.

- Media info (android) = 640 x 480 (actually 8 tall, with black bars padding it's height to 480)
- VLC (android) 640 x 480 (actually 8 tall, with black bars padding it's height to 480)
- Photo editor (android) = 44880 x 480

I have a link to it for anybody who wants to examine it directly. (It's only 401.61 kb.)

https://www.mediafire.com/file/j45w8527f83yeq9/Barbie_%25280480%252CRESULT%2529.7z/file

I've tried using FFmpeg before, and it never did anything so insane.

Here is FFmpeg's log file for it. What caused this awful result (so that I can avoid it in the future)? Also, how do I achieve the DESIRED result (in 1 pass, if possible, because I'm unsure if a GUI version of FFmpeg can do 2-pass operations)?

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -y -i "/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/Barbie (1080,ORIGINAL).mp4" -ss 00:04:44 -to 00:04:54 -vf "crop=1870:20:20:0","scale=640x480:flags=lanczos" "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/Barbie (0480,RESULT).mp4"

ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
  configuration: --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=v4l2 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libopus --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libass --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --enable-libxvid --enable-filters --enable-openssl --enable-librtmp --disable-protocol='udp,udplite' --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopenh264 --enable-jni --prefix=/home/silentlexx/AndroidstudioProjects/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/build/arm-api18-r13b --sysroot=/home/silentlexx/Android/android-ndk-r13b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm --arch=arm --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-pic --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffnvcodec --disable-avdevice --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-symver --cross-prefix=/home/silentlexx/Android/android-ndk-r13b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --target-os=android --enable-cross-compile --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs='-lgnustl_static -lm -lpng -l:libz.so -lpthread' --enable-asm --enable-neon --enable-small
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/Barbie (1080,ORIGINAL).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41isomiso2
    creation_time   : 2024-01-04T01:46:07.000000Z
  Duration: 00:45:33.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3404 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3272 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-06-25T13:25:03.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-06-25T13:25:03.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] using SAR=561/8
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/Barbie (0480,RESULT).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x480 [SAR 561:8 DAR 187:2], q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-06-25T13:25:03.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-06-25T13:25:03.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 aac
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.30 bitrate=   1.3kbits/s speed=0.00485x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.71 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=0.0115x    
frame=   16 fps=0.3 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.60 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=0.0253x    
frame=   51 fps=0.8 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.76 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=0.0433x    
frame=   89 fps=1.4 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.04 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=0.0628x    
frame=  125 fps=1.9 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.22 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=0.0806x    
frame=  155 fps=2.4 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:06.22 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=0.0952x    
frame=  188 fps=2.9 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.33 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=0.111x    
frame=  219 fps=3.3 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:08.40 bitrate= 249.5kbits/s speed=0.127x    
frame=  244 fps=3.6 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:09.72 bitrate= 215.6kbits/s speed=0.145x    
frame=  300 fps=4.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=     410kB time=00:00:09.98 bitrate= 336.0kbits/s speed=0.148x    
video:239kB audio:159kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.896691%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] frame I:11    Avg QP:18.89  size:  2003
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] frame P:143   Avg QP:20.31  size:  1034
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] frame B:146   Avg QP:21.79  size:   509
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] consecutive B-frames: 24.3% 25.3% 21.0% 29.3%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] mb I  I16..4: 24.5% 74.7%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] mb P  I16..4: 15.5% 15.1%  0.0%  P16..4: 12.3%  2.0%  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:54.9%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] mb B  I16..4:  2.3%  0.9%  0.0%  B16..8: 24.2%  1.4%  0.0%  direct: 0.7%  skip:70.6%  L0:43.8% L1:55.4% BI: 0.8%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] 8x8 transform intra:52.4% inter:99.4%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 6.9% 15.3% 0.8% inter: 1.5% 5.2% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] i16 v,h,dc,p: 92%  2%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 78%  1% 21%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 74%  1% 21%  1%  1%  2%  0%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45%  2% 52%  1%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] ref P L0: 59.2%  5.3% 25.7%  9.6%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] ref B L0: 77.2% 19.8%  3.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] ref B L1: 97.0%  3.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf6786180] kb/s:195.34
[aac @ 0xf6786880] Qavg: 457.489
```

Comment: What's the size of the black bars on each side?

Comment: Try adding `,"setsar=1"` after `"scale=640x480:flags=lanczos"`. The current SAR and DAR of the output are: SAR 561:8 DAR 187:2

Comment: (at)Gyan, I'll assume that you are asking what is the size of the black bars on the left & right sides of the ORIGINAL video. In that case, 20 pixels for the left side & 20 pixels for the right side. If you meant the RESULTING video, the link that I posted to it should still be functional, so everybody can examine it directly.

Comment: UPDATE, Using the (original) video, I used a new (but related) command. (-ss 00:04:44 -to 00:04:54 -vf "scale=640x480:flags=lanczos")(Remember, the GUI handles the input/output parts of the command separately.) The results with THAT command look okay, but instead of being 640 x 480, it's 853 x 480. Let me know if you want me to post the RESULT somewhere. (It's only 656 kb.)

Comment: 2ND UPDATE, I'll have to be more informative about this tomorrow because it's late now, but I did another related test on the original video. (-ss 00:04:44 -to 00:04:54 -vf "crop=1870:20:20:0") EVERYTHING agrees that it's resolution is 1870 x 20.

Comment: @ShuttittUppitt Did you try adding `setsar=1`? Example: `-ss 00:04:44 -to 00:04:54 -vf "crop=1870:20:20:0,scale=640x480:flags=lanczos,setsar=1"`. Note that the resolution of the video is 640x480, but the video player may stretch it. After adding `setsar=1`, make sure your video player setting are configured to display the video "pixel to pixel" (without stretching and without adding black margins). Note that currently, MediaInfo shows: Display aspect ratio 93.500

Answer (score 0):

Finally, success. After analyzing my attempts to crop it, I realised that my OLD crop command was cropping it's height to 20. It's embarrassing that I made that mistake, because my text file where I collected information on how to do certain things in FFmpeg had the command explained correctly. Whatever. At least testing this with a 10 second clip saved me some time. The CORRECT command to accomplish what I am trying to do is this, which gives me exactly the result that I want.

```
-ss 00:04:44 -to 00:04:54 -vf "crop=1870:1080:22:0","scale=640x480:flags=lanczos","setsar=1"
```

To everybody who helped me with this (Gyan & Rotem), thanks. By the way, how do I tag an answer/comment as the preferred answer? (I assume the "Up arrow button" to it's left is used, but I'm new to that sort of thing.)